How to do L2 distance computation of 8-bit integer vectors using AVX512 or AVX2?
I want to do L2 distance computation using SIMD and AVX512 or AVX2 to speed up the vector search component.
Now I use AVX512 to process 16 integers of type int32 each iteration. How can I sum the value of 16 int32 integers in the AVX512 register to get the real distance value?
My code is below:
static float
L2SqrSQ8(const int8_t *pVect1v, const int8_t *pVect2v, size_t qty) {
    size_t i;
    const int8_t *x = pVect1v;
    const int8_t *y = pVect2v;
    qty = 32;
    __m512i sum = _mm512_setzero_si512();
    for (int i = 0; i < qty; i += 16) {
        __m128i xx = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)(x + i));
        __m128i yy = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)(y + i));
        __m512i xx_ext = _mm512_cvtepi8_epi32(xx);
        __m512i yy_ext = _mm512_cvtepi8_epi32(yy);
        __m512i sub = _mm512_sub_epi32(xx_ext, yy_ext);
        __m512i square = _mm512_mullo_epi32(sub, sub)
        sum = _mm512_add_epi32(square, sum);
    }
    return 0.0; // TODO, accumulate the 16 integers in *sum*
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     int8_t a0[32] = {1, 2, 3, -4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -127, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, -24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32};
    int8_t a1[32] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 127, 12, -13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, -20, 21, 22, 23, 24, -25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33};
    L2SqrSQ8((int8_t*)a0, (int8_t*)a1, 32);
    return 0;
}

I just start learning SIMD programming, so if someone can give me advice or review of my naive code, I will be grateful!

Worth a try compiling it on the Intel compiler to see if it can auto-vectorise it (and checking what the assembler code for your present compiler looks like. GCC can also do some vector code if linked with the right libraries.  Otherwise my suggestion would be promote them to a double length int16 so that x^2 will fit in the vector element.

gcc and clang easily vectorize that code using vpmovsxbw, vpsubw, vpmaddwd and vpadd: https://godbolt.org/z/Ge3Gre7of (try other -march= arguments for AVX512). gcc does some weird vextracti128 instructions, and clang tends to aggressively unroll loops.

The only 8bit product in SSE/AVX is pmaddubsw but that multiplies a int8 by an uint8 and accumulates pairs of them with saturation, which is hard to use in this case. For a faster distance calculation between 8bit vectors, you can use psadbw to compute the sum of absolute distances (i.e. L1 distance) between uint8 vectors (for signed inputs, you can first xor each element with 0x80)

Using vpmaddwd like chtz suggested would do one step of horizontal summing for free, and be 4x more efficient in terms of multiplying on Intel CPUs.  (Twice as many products per instruction with half as many uops per instruction.)    The end result would still be a vector of 32-bit partial sums which you need to sum horizontally after the loop. (And then convert to float for no apparent reason?  Are you expecting the partial sums to fit in int32_t but the total across elements to be too large, or something?  Otherwise why not have the function return int and let the caller convert?)

See Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction) and specifically Fastest method to calculate sum of all packed 32-bit integers using AVX512 or AVX2 for the hsum part.  Inside the loop, vpmaddwd is _mm512_madd_epi16, and you want _mm512_cvtepi8_epi16 with 256-bit input vectors.

The biggest possible difference between two int8 is 255 (=127-(-128)). If you square this you have 65025=0xfe01, i.e., you can sum up (slightly more than) 0x10000=65536 values without overflowing uint32_t (half that without overflowing int32_t).

See https://uops.info/ for performance details of instructions like vpmaddwd vs. vpmulld
